# How to edit a row in parse class

Tags: android, parse-platform, row, edit

I have my custom classes for my app in parse and I want to edit a row from a class. How do I achieve this thing.

I am new to parse and struggling with object ids.

please help.

Comment: what do you mean by "**I want to edit a row from a class**" ?

Comment: Can you add more more details https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#objects-updating You can check this link for how to update the objectID, as well as other elements in the row.